# What do multicast MAC addresses mean?

Tags: ip, ipv6, ethernet, ipv4, tcp

When booting up a Linux server, some multicast packets are sent out. The destination MAC address is `33:33:00:00:00:02`.

I wonder if the multicast address is well known? Does it have some special meaning? Is there a well-known multicast MAC address list?

Comment: I looked it up with this http://blog.wlancontroller.com/?p=67 - OUI Lookup no results.  I have never heard / seen that specific address before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mapping of IP multicast addresses to MAC multicast addresses is many-to-one, so technically that MAC address could correspond to lots of different IP addresses. However, in this case, the IP address in question is almost certainly `ff01::2`, which is the all-routers multicast address. The host is probably sending a router solicitation message.

Multicast MAC addresses beginning with `33:33:` are all used by IPv6, but you won't find them in the OUI registry because the IETF did not officially register that prefix with the IEEE (it would have meant too many individual OUI values to register).

Comment: Some well-known multicast MAC addresses are listed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#Ethernet). Using `33:33` as the beginning of the destination MAC address for IPv6 multicasts is defined in [RFC 2464](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2464#section-7).